# form is a type and cannot be used in an expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm relatively new to coding, doing this in a class for school, and I'm getting a new error we've never encountered in class while doing a project the teacher has given us to do on our own without step-by-step help from him.

In `Application.Designer.vb` I am getting the following error.

> 'form' is a type in 'project' and cannot be used as an expression.

The line of code I'm getting this from is:

```
Me.Mainform = Global.Project.Form
```

What's causing this and how do I go about fixing it.

Comment: When picking a name for a project, try to pick a better name than "Project".  When picking a name for a form, try to pick a better name than "Form".  Good names matter a lot and if you skimp then you *will* get into trouble like this.

Comment: Old question, but I ran into this issue when I accidentally made set the form's "New" constructor as private.  Making it public fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have created something (probably a form) that has a name of Form ... change the name of your form to something like "myform"